# Sort Several Select Options by Value Attribute in same page

Tags: javascript, jquery

Supose i have

```
<select id="select_0_0">
    <option value="3">3</option>
    <option value="1">1</option>
    <option value="a">a</option>
</select>
<select id="select_0_1">
    <option value="abc">abc</option>
    <option value="a">a</option>
    <option value="1">1</option>
    <option value="3">3</option>
    <option value="B">B</option>
    <option value="2">2</option>
</select>
...
<select id="select_n_m">
    <option value="xxx">xxx</option>
    <option value="zzz">zzz</option>
    <option value="1">1</option>
    <option value="3">3</option>
</select>
```

And many more like this in samepage.

How can i sort all selects with javascript, to get this:

```
<select id="select_0_0">
    <option value="1">1</option>
    <option value="2">2</option>
    <option value="a">a</option>
</select>
<select id="select_0_1">
    <option value="1">1</option>
    <option value="2">2</option>
    <option value="3">3</option>
    <option value="a">a</option>
    <option value="abc">abc</option>
    <option value="B">B</option>
</select>
...
<select id="select_n_m">
    <option value="1">1</option>
    <option value="3">3</option>
    <option value="xxx">xxx</option>
    <option value="zzz">zzz</option>
</select>
```

Code i tried:

```
$("select").html($("option").sort(function (a, b) {
return a.text == b.text ? 0 : a.text < b.text ? -1 : 1
}))
```

But it combines alls options of all selects in every select. Is there a solution?
Thank you in advance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should iterate through the `select` elements and then sort the children:

```
$('select').each(function () {
    $("option", this).sort(function (a, b) {
        return a.text.localeCompare(b.text);
    }).appendTo(this);
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/ew8f8dak/

Answer (score 0):

You give `id` to the `select` fields, but do not use them. Use two `for` loops - both starts from 0, the first goes until the number of rows, the second, inner one until the number of elements in the row. It works best when you have the same number of `select` in every row.

This way you can get the id of every `select` element, and you can use this id to sort every `select` one by one.

Edit: As I am not familiar with jquery, I was not able to include code. Since then I looked it up, and you can use this to select an item by it's id: `$("#itemID")`.

So, the code should look something like this (again, I'm not familiar with jquery):

```
for(int i = 0; i < numberOfRows; i++){
    for(int j = 0; j < numberOfEelements; j++){
        selectID = "select_" + i + "_" + j;
        $("#selectID").html($("option").sort(function (a, b) {
           return a.text == b.text ? 0 : a.text < b.text ? -1 : 1
        }))
    }
}
```